# Azure Function with Entity Framework or Normal Sql query

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-functions

Could you please help with what is better where Entity Framework or normal Sql query, I personally would like to use Entity Framework with Linq to SQL however I faced certain challenges today like there is no .ToList() or .FirstOrDefault() option available and also there are compatibilty issues using Entity Framework with .net Standard 2.0, so, anyone experienced the same and help what would be better approach.

Comment: ToList() or ToArray() is quite important to how EF works given the way it [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data](lazy loads data). Your question is rather vague, could you elaborate. 
EF works fine with .net Standard for myself so could you add some details about the configuration of your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you need to using the namespace of `System.Linq`

.ToList() or .FirstOrDefault() option is available at .NET CORE 2.0 and these two method are extension methods under `System.Linq`. So we need to use `System.Linq` 
 namespace.

We can see below screenshot of my project.

[image]